# POW, MIA and KIA

Tags: capitalization

When should you use title case?  Why would anyone use title case in these sentences?

> He was a Prisoner of War (POW).
>   **OR**
>   He was a prisoner of war (POW).
>
> He was Missing in Action (MIA).
>   **OR**
>   He was missing in action (MIA).
>
> He was Killed in Action (KIA).
>   **OR**
>   He was killed in action (KIA).

Answer (score 5):

All are lowercase in ordinary text, even though their initials are capitalized, like *television*, lowercase but with capitalized initials: TV. The phrases *prisoner of war* and *missing in action* are lowercase in the U.S. Department of Defense dictionary, available online at 
[www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/dictionary.pdf](http://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/dictionary.pdf). Maybe *killed in action* didn't need defining.

Comment: Agreed, although I'd _probably_ capitalise the words if I introduced the initialism first: "_He was a POW (Prisoner of War)_" because you're not _using_ the words in a sentence, and it highlights the initials. Whether that's correct or not, I don't know.